# Selenium "chrome is being controlled by automated software" message stuck in my browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I've run some Selenium script and then tried to run it using another profile which is one of my regular profiles located in the general Chrome user data folder (e.g. `C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`), thereafter I understood it's not a good practice and now I'm using the Selenium default profile that created from scratch for every new run.

But from that moment, the message "chrome is being controlled by automated software" on the header of my regular browser (no matter which profile) stuck and I don't know how to remove it.

[image]

I tried to see if there is some extension but doest find nothing, I suspect that it's might be some files Selenium added but can't find something helpful.

Do anyone know how to remove this message permanently?

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Try the code and let me know if it works for you or not